# Excel Averaging the last 6 cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average

I have an excel sheet where I need to average the last entries in a row, and have it output to the same cell. The issue is that I will have blanks in there. Can someone help? Below is an example.

```
=IF($G9 > 0,(AVERAGEIF($K9:$BS9,"<>0")),0)
```

[image]

Comment: Is   $24287.25 the answer you want? It looks as if it may be the average of row 3, columns headed 1 to 6 in your screenshot, but it's not very clear as these would be the first 6 entries in the row not the last 6 and I can't see how it matches up with the formula.

Answer (score 0):

So blank cells shouldn't impact the average, so you must be trying to avoid the cells with a value of 0. If so, then this should work for you, right?

```
=AVERAGEIF(B2:P2,"<>0")
```

[image]

Or is the problem more complicated than this, where you want to average the most recent 6 non-zero cells? That wasn't mentioned in the question, but maybe that's what you're asking?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Please for give me for not explaining better. What I am trying to do is average the last 6 entries minus blanks and zeros. The other issue I have is that until week 6 (Row G) I will have less than 6 entries to average, and that will come up with a #NUM error. I heard a VBA can be used but that is something I have no idea on how to start.